# working on mongo's data without storing it to disk

Tags: python, mongodb

I am storing a phantom cine file to mongodb. I am able to retrieve the file and store it to the disk. But is there a way I can work on the desired data without storing it to disk. The question arises because the data we store and retrieve is in binary form. So is there a effective way in which I can work and process the data on mongo's document itself? Please help
This is the way I am storing the data:

```
import numpy
from pymongo import MongoClient
import gridfs
db = MongoClient().CINEfs_example
fs = gridfs.GridFS(db)
CIN=open('testing.cin','rb').read()
with fs.new_file(
    filename='testing.cin',
    content_type='video') as fp:
        fp.write(CIN)
```

And this is the way I retrieve the file:

```
import os
file1=fs.get_last_version('testing.cin').read()
with open('test.cin','wb') as file:
    file.write(file1)
```

Now I dont want the file to be stored on the disk just want to work on the mongo directly. 
for example in the above code I want file1 to be encoded as .cin file and work directly. Is this possible or is there an alternate way? Please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking how to manipulate the binary content directly in MongoDB without extracting it?    This is somewhat possible by "diving under" GridFS and accessing portions of the chunked-up content.  But the question is:   what sort of "direct operations" do you wish to perform?

Comment: You can always read/write with a socket. As in stream directly to a client. Is this what you are talking about? It's just that your example code here is very basic so it is not really clear what what you intend to do.

Comment: So my question actually is that I have a video file which is stored in the binary format on GridFS. Once I extract it and save it to the disk as a .cin file I can analyze the video by dividing into frames or take certain images etc. But the minimum size of the video file I will be working on is 1GB and I cant afford to save that file to disk everytime. So I want an alteernative such that I dont store the file to disk and do the Video Analysis on the Mongo's Document itself. Is this possible? Please Help

Comment: The thing is I dont want to write it to the disk I just want to do the video analysis on Mongo's document